# Querystring with Hash Key to access search results

Tags: c#, hash, key, md5, salt

I need help with this asap (I was just asked to come up with a solution to this for tomorrow morning). The lead developer asked me to come up with a possible already existing solution to the following problem:

We have this C# search result page used publicly by third party websites, but we will be adding access restriction through hash keys passed onto the query string.

To start, the third party website developer will visit a new page we will create to auto generate the hash key based on the state they are in. They will then add the key to their links. When we have a request from one of their links we will try to match the key with what we have in the database in order to allow access to results - we would also like to check extra information like domain/IP address to prevent spoofing and other kinds of attacks.

Another consideration is: can we make this key system dynamic in such way that it would change over time, but third party developers wouldn't need to come back to us to update what they have - a intermediate key?.

The question is what is the best solution for this case scenario? Is there already something similar out there? Is using hash keys in the query string the right/best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Generally in this case, you have an identifier and a shared secret.

The identifier is passed in the query for you to identify the user.  The shared secret is used in a hashing algorithm to provide a checksum of the request.  This is commonly sent in the query string (easy on the third party) or as a HTTP header.

Amazon uses this type of digital signing in AWS with HMAC-SHA256.  See MSDN documentation on [System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256.aspx) and AWS documentation on [Authenticating Requests](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html).  MD5 or SHA alone would probably work fine in your case as well.

You can maintain a per-user shared key assuming you have a way of distributing it to your client.